# Compilers and programming languages designing (just curiosity)

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science

That's a question I've been recently thinking about. As a computer engineering student, I would like to know which areas of computer science or computer engineering focus on compilers particularly, due to the fact that:

I will study at a faculty in which there are some different specializations:

-Computers (CPU architectures, operating systems, computer networks, real-time systems and some other hardware issues, the one I like)

-Software (Software architectures, databases design, web services, advanced programming concepts, distributed systems...)

-Computer science(algorithms, logic, graphics, artificial intelligence...everything purely theorical, I guess)

And the last specialization has got a subject called "compilers", so here's my question: are compilers only and exclusively related to logic, algorithms and things like this? Is there any chance to learn everything involving compilers on one's own or by facing it from another viewpoint?  Does any other specialization focus on them?

Who can give me a general view of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers are at the intersection of just about all branches of CS. Although they draw heavily from a few specific disciplines, building a good compiler requires a good understanding of numerous branches of CS.

The front-end of a compiler leverages techniques from formal language theory (regular languages, regular expressions, finite automata, grammars, parsing, etc.), theoretical CS (type systems), and many other disciplines. There's also issues of language design and implementation, which typically is right at the intersection of systems programming and theoretical CS.

Code generators rely on a deep understanding of how machines actually work. You need to be familiar with memory layout, registers, assembly instructions, processor pipelining, etc.

Compiler optimizations often have a strong theoretical basis (control-flow diagrams, meet semilattices, transfer functions, graph coloring, etc.) but are motivated by practical concerns (parallelism, branch prediction, etc.)

There's also concerns about the language runtime, such as garbage collection, dynamic optimization, etc. These require some strong theoretical guarantees, yet are definitely challenging systems problems as well.

There are even some AI techniques that show up: some global flow analyses use data structures tuned by machine learning, and superoptimization sometimes works by using Markov chain Monte Carlo techniques.

Hope this helps!